# HTML: How to get multiple timers to combine

Tags: javascript, html, user-input, setinterval

I am building a timer based on user inputs. Below is how to code should work:
User inputs:
Time on: 30s

Time off: 10s

Number of sets: 4

Number of exercises per set: 5

Rest in between sets: 30s

With the above user inputs the timer will do this:
[image: Working Timer]

Hopefully that makes sense on what It is supposed to do. I am currently trying to implement the rest in between sets. Does anyone know how I could make that happen with how my code currently is? **Also totalTime already includes the amount of time the rest in between sets would add on if that helps.**

```js
var numsets = document.getElementById("userInput1");
var numex = document.getElementById("userInput2");
var numwork = document.getElementById("userInput3");
var numrest = document.getElementById("userInput4");
var numrestafterset = document.getElementById("userInput5");

var sets;
var OGtimeon;
var OGtimeoff;
var totalTime;
var timeRemaining;
var hasBeenStarted = false;  // Boolean value to test what time to use

var isTimeON = true;
var timeon;
var timeoff;
var timeonRemaining;
var timeoffRemaining;
var setsRemaining;
var OGsets;
var Prepare;
var OGExPS;
var OGTOASets;
var ExercisePS;
var RestAfterS;
var Intervals
var j = 0;
var ExercisesRemaining;
var RestRemaining;

// function sleep(milliseconds) { //function I found online to create a sleep function
//     const date = Date.now();
//     let currentDate = null;
//     do {
//       currentDate = Date.now();
//     } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
//   }

// function updateRest() {
//     if (RestAfterS > 0) {
//         interval3 = setInterval(RestCount, 1000);
//     }
//     else {
//         startTime();
//     }

// function RestCount() {
//     while (RestAfterS != 0) {
//         RestAfterS--;
//     }
//     j = 0;
// }

function updatePrep() {
    if  (hasBeenStarted == false) {
        Prepare = 5;
        interval2 = setInterval(PrepCount, 1000);
    }
    else {
        startTime();
    }
}


function PrepCount() {
    let seconds = parseFloat(Prepare) % 60;

    if (Prepare == 0) {
        clearInterval(interval2);
        startTime();
    }
    else {
        PWR.innerHTML = "Get Ready!";
        textarea.innerHTML = Prepare;
        console.log(Prepare);
        Prepare--;
    }
}



function startTime() {

    // Set values in code
    OGsets = numsets.value;
    OGtimeon = numwork.value;
    OGtimeoff = numrest.value;
    OGTOASets = numrestafterset.value;
    OGExPS = numex.value;
    

    timeon = (hasBeenStarted)? timeonRemaining : OGtimeon;
    timeoff = (hasBeenStarted)? timeoffRemaining : OGtimeoff;
    sets = (hasBeenStarted)? setsRemaining : OGsets;
    ExercisePS = (hasBeenStarted)? ExercisesRemaining : OGExPS;
    RestAfterS = (hasBeenStarted)? RestRemaining : OGTOASets;

    // How much time on timer
    // Var = (expression)? true : false this is basically an if statement
    totalTime = (hasBeenStarted)? timeRemaining : ((parseFloat(OGtimeon)*parseFloat(sets)*parseFloat(ExercisePS))+(parseFloat(OGTOASets)*(parseFloat(sets)-1))+(parseFloat(OGtimeoff)*(parseFloat(sets)*(parseFloat(ExercisePS)-1))));
    Intervals = ((parseFloat(sets)*parseFloat(ExercisePS))+((parseFloat(sets)-1))+((parseFloat(sets)*(parseFloat(ExercisePS)-1))));
    hasBeenStarted = true;
    

    // Start timer
    interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
}



function updateCountdown() {
    IntervalsLeft.innerHTML = Intervals;
    setsLeft.innerHTML = sets;

    var minutes= Math.floor (parseFloat(totalTime) / 60);
    var seconds = parseFloat(totalTime) % 60;
    if (seconds < 10) {
        textareaRemaining.innerHTML = minutes + ":0" + seconds;
    } else {
        textareaRemaining.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }

    // Update TimeON / Time OFF
    if(isTimeON){          
        PWR.innerHTML = "Work!";    
        textarea.innerHTML = timeon;
        timeon--;
        if(timeon == 0){
            isTimeON = false;
            timeon = OGtimeon;
            Intervals--;
            IntervalsLeft.innerHTML = Intervals;
        }
        
    }
    //BELOW IS THE AREA I AM STUCK ON

    else{
        
       textarea.innerHTML = timeoff;
       timeoff--;
       PWR.innerHTML = "Rest!";
       if(timeoff == 0){
            isTimeON = true;
            timeoff = OGtimeoff;
            j++;
            Intervals--;
            IntervalsLeft.innerHTML = Intervals;
            if (j == OGExPS) {
                sets--;
                //updateRest();
                j = 0;
            }
             
        }
    }
        if( totalTime == 0 ){
            clearTimeout(interval);
            hasBeenStarted = false;
            console.log(sets);
            sets--;
            setsLeft.innerHTML = sets;
            PWR.innerHTML = "OMG YOU'RE DONE";
        }
        totalTime--;    
    }


    

    function updateRest() {
        if (RestAfterS > 0) {
            interval3 = setInterval(RestCount, 5000);
        }
        else {
            startTime();
        }
    }
    
    function RestCount() {
        while (RestAfterS != 0) {
            RestAfterS--;
            PWR.innerHTML = "Set Rest!";
            textarea.innerHTML = RestAfterS;
        }
        j = 0;
        clearInterval(interval3);
    }




function stop(){
    timeRemaining = totalTime;
    timeonRemaining = timeon;
    timeoffRemaining = timeoff;
    RestRemaining = RestAfterS;
    ExercisesRemaining = OGExPS;
    setsRemaining = sets;
    clearTimeout(interval);
    // document.getElementById("Counter").innerHTML = j;
    

}
```

```css
p {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
#userInput1 {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#userInput2 {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#userInput3 {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#userInput4 {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#userInput5 {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#Prepare {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#sets {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#timeon {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#timeoff {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#TotalTime {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#Counter {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


input {
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Countdown From Scratch.css" />
</head>
<script src="Countdown From Scratch.js" defer></script>
<body>
    <label>Number of Sets </label>    
    <input id="userInput1" type="numsets" value = "0"/>
    <label>Number of Exercises per Set </label>    
    <input id="userInput2" type="numex" value = "0"/>
    <label>Time to Work </label>
    <input id="userInput3" type="numwork" value = "0"/>
    <label>Time to Rest </label>
    <input id="userInput4" type="numrest" value = "0"/>
    <label>Time Inbetween Sets </label>
    <input id="userInput5" type="numrestafterset" value = "0"/>   

    <p id="Prepare"></p>
    <div id="sets"> </div>
    <div id="timeon"> </div>
    <div id="timeoff"> </div>
    <div id="TotalTime"> </div>
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="00:00"></textarea>
    <textarea id="PWR" placeholder="Hello!"></textarea>
    <textarea id="textareaRemaining" placeholder="00:00"></textarea>
    <textarea id="setsLeft" placeholder="00"></textarea>
    <textarea id="IntervalsLeft" placeholder="00"></textarea>

    
    <button onclick="updatePrep()">Start time</button>
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop time</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this really isn't clear. What does it mean to "work" and to "rest"?

Comment: This is a tabata timer, so work is the timeon ( the time you would actually do your workout) and rest is timeoff (the break you get after you completed your exercise) Does that make sense?

Comment: [Here's some maybe similar code](https://github.com/greggman/interval-timer)

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a rough idea of what you are trying to accomplish here, but please let me know if I have misinterpreted anything.

Suppose you want to execute a sequence of effects with some duration in between them. To keep the example small, we'll use `console.log` as a stand-in for any effect you'd want to execute (for instance, setting the `innerHTML` of a DOM element).

As a first example, here we wait for 1 second, display "Hello", then wait for 1.5 seconds and display "There":

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Hello');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('There');
  }, 1500);
}, 1000);
```

We can clarify this by describing the common parts as a function:

```
function logAfter(message, delay, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(message);
    if (callback) callback();
  }, delay);
}
```

Then our example can be written as:

```
logAfter('Hello', 1000, () => {
  logAfter('There', 1500);
});
```

As another example that is perhaps more relevant to your project, here is how we can create a "loop" that performs an effect multiple times:

```
function logNAfter(message, times, delay, callback) {
  if (times === 0 && callback) {
    callback();
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(message);
      logNAfter(message, times-1, delay, callback);
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

We could use this to display "Hi There!" 3 times, each separated by half a second, and then display "Goodbye!" once, 2 seconds later:

```
logNAfter('Hi There!', 3, 500, () => {
  logAfter('Goodbye!', 2000);
});
```

In theory, you could create an arbitrarily-long sequence of appropriately spaced effects in this way. However, I should also mention that many would prefer to describe these effects as [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s instead:

```
function logAfter(message, delay) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(message);
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}

function logNAfter(message, times, delay) {
  if (times === 0) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    return logAfter(message, delay)
      .then(() => logNAfter(message, times-1, delay));
  }
}
```

The original examples then become:

```
logAfter('Hello', 1000)
  .then(() => logAfter('There', 1500));

logNAfter('Hi There!', 3, 500)
  .then(() => logAfter('Goodbye!', 2000));
```

This is arguably only a slight improvement over the callback-style approach above, but it is much clearer if you are able to use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function logAfter(message, delay) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(message);
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}

async function logNAfter(message, times, delay) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    await logAfter(message, delay);
  }
}

async function demoSequence1() {
  await logAfter('Hello', 1000);
  await logAfter('There', 1500);
}

async function demoSequence2() {
  await logNAfter('Hi There!', 3, 500);
  await logAfter('Goodbye!', 2000);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, let me look this over and I will let you know if I have any questions. Thank you for answering!

Comment: I am unfamiliar with what you described above, but I believe I understand everything except the "callback" part. Could you explain what that does?

Comment: Definitely! Think of a timer as an effect that just waits without performing any computation (this is often called "sleeping"). There are many ways to incorporate this kind of effect into a programming language, but two common strategies are these: [1] have the effect _block_ all other computations while it is occurring or [2] allow other computations to occur while the effect is occurring. JavaScript adopts the second of these: when you call the `setTimeout` function, statements after it will get executed immediately afterwards. [continued >>]

Comment: In order to execute some computation after the timeout has completed, you need to _provide it as a function_ to the `setTimeout` function (this is the "callback", as if the `setTimeout` function is saying: "I'll call you back when I am done producing this effect"). In general, when you want to produce an asynchronous effect in JavaScript (`setTimeout` is an example), you need to construct a function that answers the question: "what do I want to do once this effect is completed?". Does that help?

Comment: I think so? So are you saying if I want my original function to start going again, I would put that as my callback?

Answer (score 0):

I like Williams suggested of breaking it down into different timers that could be controlled easier by the user. However, using this approach, I personally ran into the issue of how to pause the timer.

I decided to take a slightly different approach. From the table given, there is a fairly clear pattern of how the timer needs to be set up.The timer generally alternates between "Workout time" and "Rest time" for the whole duration. Rest time can take 3 different values:

1. Rest time between exercises
2. Rest time between Sets
3. The workout is complete

Since all of these values are known when the the values are inputed, my approach is set up the course of the timer before starting the timer. This creates a little bit of setup time but I believe this is negotiable and will not impact performance heavily. To do this, I created a created an array before starting the timer. Each item in this array contains data including the total time remaining, the current set, the label (Working out or resting), and the label timer. After creating this array, we can just create a timer that is based off the number of items in the array. I hope that this little explanation helps you understand my solution a little bit better.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  td, th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  } 
</style>


<head>
  <title>Timer</title>
</head>


<body>
<!-- Inputs -->
<h2>Inputs</h2>
  <p>
    <label for="sets-input">Number of Sets: </label>
    <input type="number" id="sets-input" min="1" max="3600">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="exercises-input">Number of Exersizes per Set: </label>
    <input type="number" id="exercises-input" min="1" max="3600">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="workout-input">Exersise Time:  </label>
    <input type="number" id="workout-input" min="1" max="3600">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="exersiseRest-input">Rest between exersises: </label>
    <input type="number" id="exersiseRest-input" min="1" max="3600">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="setRest-input">Rest between Sets: </label>
    <input type="number" id="setRest-input" min="1" max="3600">
  </p>

<!-- Buttons -->
<p>
  <button id="start-button">Start</button>
  <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
</p>


<!-- Timer Display  -->
  <h2>Outputs:</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Total Time Remaining: </th>
      <td id="timer-display">???</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th>Set Number: </th>
      <td id="set-display">???</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th id="label-display">???</th>
      <td id="labelTimer-display">???</td>
    </tr> 
    
  </table>

  <script src="tabada.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

**Tabada.js**

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// HTML
var setsInput = document.getElementById("sets-input");
var exersisesInput = document.getElementById("exercises-input");
var workoutInput = document.getElementById("workout-input");
var exersiseRestInput = document.getElementById("exersiseRest-input");
var setRestInput = document.getElementById("setRest-input");

var timerDisplay = document.getElementById("timer-display");
var setDisplay = document.getElementById("set-display");
var labelDisplay = document.getElementById("label-display");
var labelTimerDisplay = document.getElementById("labelTimer-display");

var startButton = document.getElementById("start-button");
var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset-button");

// JavaScript
var sets = 2;
var exersises = 3;
var workout = 5;
var exersiseRest = 2;
var setRest = 3;

var totalTime = -1;
var myInterval = -1;
var tabadaArray = [];
var tabadaIndex = 0;


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BUTTON FUNCTIONS
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Start / Pause Button
startButton.addEventListener("click", function(event){

  // Set up Tabada Timer
  if (totalTime == -1){
    collectInputs();        // Comment this line for testing without inputs
    calculateTotalTime();
    createTabadaArray();
  }

  // Start timer
  if (myInterval == -1){
    startButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
    myInterval = setInterval(tabadaTimer, 1000);
  }

  // Pause timer
  else{
    startButton.innerHTML = "Start";
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = -1
  }
});


// Reset Button
resetButton.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  
  // Stop Timer
  clearInterval(myInterval);   
 
  // Refresh Timer Display
  calculateTotalTime(); 
  updateOutputs(totalTime, 1, 'Workout', workout);               
  totalTime=-1;  // Alows user to change input values before clicking start button.

  // Reset start / pause button
  myInterval = -1;                  
  startButton.innerHTML = "Start"; 
});


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SETUP FOR TABADA TIMER
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function collectInputs(){
  sets = parseFloat(setsInput.value);
  exersises = parseFloat(exersisesInput.value);
  workout = parseFloat(workoutInput.value);
  exersiseRest = parseFloat(exersiseRestInput.value);
  setRest = parseFloat(setRestInput.value);
}

function calculateTotalTime(){
  let totalWorkoutTime = workout * exersises * sets;
  let totalExersiseRest = exersiseRest * (exersises - 1) * sets;
  let totalSetsRest = setRest * (sets - 1);

  totalTime = totalWorkoutTime + totalExersiseRest + totalSetsRest;
}

function createTabadaArray() {
  tabadaIndex = 0;    // Global variable used for tabada timer
  tabadaArray = [];
  
  for( let set=1; set<=sets; set++ ){
    for( let exersise=1; exersise<=exersises; exersise++){

      // Workout
      addTimeBlock(set, 'Workout', workout);

      // Exersise Rest
      if ( exersise < exersises){
        addTimeBlock(set, 'Rest', exersiseRest);
      }

      // Set Rest
      else if( set < sets){
        addTimeBlock(set, 'Rest', setRest);
      }
      
      // Done
      else{break;}   // Very end exersize has no rest, so we must break the loop.
    }
  }
}

function addTimeBlock(set, label, labelTime) {

  // Add a sub timer to the array (workout, exersice rest, or set rest)
  for (let i=labelTime; i>0; i--) {
    tabadaArray.push({
      "totalTimeRemaining" : totalTime--,
      "set" : set,
      "label" : label,
      "labelTimeRemaining" : i,
    });
  }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// TABADA TIMER
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function tabadaTimer(){
  // Still time left
  if (tabadaIndex < tabadaArray.length){
    let displayInfo = tabadaArray[tabadaIndex];
    updateOutputs(  displayInfo.totalTimeRemaining, 
                    displayInfo.set,
                    displayInfo.label,
                    displayInfo.labelTimeRemaining );
    tabadaIndex++;
  }

  // End of tabada timer
  else{
    clearInterval(myInterval);        // stop timer 
    updateOutputs(0, 1, 'Rest', 0);
    totalTime = -1
  }
}

function updateOutputs(totalTimeRemaining, setNumber, label, labelTimeRemaining){
  timerDisplay.innerHTML = convertSeconds(totalTimeRemaining);
  setDisplay.innerHTML = setNumber;
  labelDisplay.innerHTML = label;
  labelTimerDisplay.innerHTML = convertSeconds(labelTimeRemaining);
}

function convertSeconds(s){
  // Seconds -> mm:ss format 

  // Calculate
  let minutes = Math.floor(s/60);
  let seconds = s%60;

  // Format
  let formattedminutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
  let formattedseconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
  return formattedminutes + ':' + formattedseconds;
}
```